# Automating comparing two excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel files.

1st file is big and has a lot of users  and their attributes (found in columns )

2nd file is my file with only my users.

The goal is to look at 1st file for the names of that are on 2nd file.

If the name is found there copy it to a csv file and if one of the columns is empty write a comment saying “Column/Attribute is not filled”

How would I go with solving this problem considering the fact that I don’t have that much experience excel advanced features.

Comment: If 1st file is sorted then VLOOKUP, otherwise MATCH & INDEX will return the attributes (or error if missing). Then an IF to return "Col not filled". Then filter and copy to csv

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you maybe write an answer to this with some photos where I can see this process or some sources I can inform and learn more about this. thank u

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set objWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\your_path\Book1.xlsx")
Set objWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\your_path\Book2.xlsx")

Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook1.Worksheets(1)
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)


Set WorkRng1 = objWorksheet1.UsedRange
Set WorkRng2 = objWorksheet2.UsedRange

For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    Rng1.Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then

            ' If match, delete
            ' your biz logic goes here

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that your question is tagged with VBA but what exactly are your requirements here?

For example, it might be worth considering to export the excel spreadsheets to XML files and then use XQuery to retrieve that information.
However, I'm not sure whether this fits your needs/requirements in terms of tools/stack.

Comment: Requird is to automate this process. Compare these two files and then copy the compared rows into an csv file. Let's say I search in the first file the user id if it the same user id, copy and paste that row to the new csv file